# Prepared Statements - Should I use php prepared statements even in queries without (?) placeholders?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

It makes perfect sense to me to use prepared statements in a query of the following type:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT phone FROM contact WHERE name = ? ";
```

However, in the following situation, does it make sense and is it useful to use prepared statements, as sometimes seen?

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT name FROM contact";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your point of interest here? If your query will not contain any external parameters, then you still can use prepared statements, or not use them at all.

Comment: The second query may be used, for example, in a combobox.

Comment: @Reshad Why is that?

Comment: @Reshad: How is that "wrong"?  That's a valid query.  You don't *need* a `WHERE` clause.  What if he *really* does want to get every row?

Comment: ah sorry I overlooked myself :) I meant in case he wants to have user input he has to write a where clause otherwise it won;t work

Comment: Thanks Desolator :If I have understood correctly what you said, can also be used prepared statements in the query will not contain any external parameters, but not strip any useful effect of this, is it? No wonder that I ask this question because some people think it should always be use prepared statements. To begin to encode in a unique way.Then take a look at the following queries from PHP manual, although in these cases has 'ORDER BY Name LIMIT', but without any placeholder (?). http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running a query without *any* user-entered variables, you can just do:

```
$db->query("SELECT name FROM contact")
```

As soon as you start entering in user-inputted data, then you *need* to use a prepared statement.

```
$db->prepare("SELECT phone FROM contact WHERE name = ?");
```

Comment: There are exceptions for user-input though - as far as I know, `IN` lists cannot be parameterised, nor can table/column names.

Comment: @halfer: Well, you can't do `IN (?)` and send an array, but you *can* do `IN (?, ?, ?)`.  Also, as for table/column names, one solution is to use a whitelist of valid values and compare the input to it.

Comment: Ah, fair enough - I didn't know they could be done individually.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, prepared statements only **need** to be used when user input is concerned. It's perfectly fine to use them in situations when no user input is concerned as well - If you're using PDO you may find it more convenient to use the same PDO connection string and query process as before, as using a different function set would require you to reopen the connection.

Comment: "as using a different function set would require you to reopen the connection." huh? You can do `$pdo->query()` or `$pdo->exec()`. No need for a new connection

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm talking about using mysqli_ or another similar set of functions. You can of course use the connection directly.